# Xamarin Android Service when app is closed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I Want the service to run even if the application is closed.

I tried this code but when I close the application it stop.

**Service Class**

```
 [Service(Exported = true, Process = "com.process_myservice")]
    class MyBackgrounding : Service
    {
        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
            => null;

        [return: GeneratedEnum]
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            new Task(() =>
            {
                //StartTimer();
                while (true)
                {
                    CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show(y++.ToString(), "body");
                    Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
                }
            }).Start();
            return StartCommandResult.StickyCompatibility;
        }
        public override bool StopService(Intent name)
        {
            return base.StopService(name);
        }
    }
```

**Start Service in the OnCreate Method**

```
StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(MyBackgrounding)));
```

**Application Running**

[the notifications are pushed while app is running or in background.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeyBE.png)

**Application Closed**

[The process still there but no notifications pushed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qExZg.png)

**Note: I don't want the service to push notifications, but I want it to record sensors data ...... pushing notifications just to try the service.**

**Thank you**

Comment: thanks, but didn't work.

Comment: Are you purposefully killing the app process? If so, you can look at using WorkManager to restart a service at timed internals (and upon each start, rescheduling the WorkManager again)